# No Matching Function for Call to

Tags: c++, sockets

In my object ' handler '
I have the following code:

```
Product tempProduct; // temporary Product storage variable
LINE481    tempProduct.setHandler(this);
```

Within my Product.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <qtimer.h>
#include "HandleTCPClient.h"


#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H

class Handler;

//Define ourselves a product class
class Product
    {

        void startTimer();

    public:
        Product();

        string seller, itemName, description, highestBidder;
        double price, min, buyingPrice, currentBid;
        int time;
        bool isSold;
        Handler handler();

        void setHandler(Handler h);

    public slots:
        void setProductToSold();

    };

#endif
```

For my Product.cpp:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include "Product.h"

Product::Product()
{
    seller = "";
    itemName = "";
    price = 0.00;
    min = 0.00;
    buyingPrice = 0.00;
    time = 0;
    description = "";
    highestBidder = "None";
    currentBid = 0.00;
}

void Product::setHandler(Handler h)
{
    handler = h;
}
```

The issue I am having:

```
HandleTCPClient.cpp: In member function âint Handler::HandleTCPClient(int, std::string, std::string)â:
HandleTCPClient.cpp:481: error: no matching function for call to âProduct::setHandler(Handler* const)â
Product.h:34: note: candidates are: void Product::setHandler(Handler)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to declare your `setHandler` function like this:

```
void Product::setHandler(Handler *h)
```

Also, inside the Product class, declare `handler` like this:

```
Handler *handler;
```

It looks like you might be more familiar with a language such as Java or Python that doesn't have an explicit pointer syntax. In C++, you must explicitly declare pointers using the `*` indication, otherwise the compiler will try to copy and pass around *value* objects (copying the whole object through its copy constructor).

Comment: Thank you so much, yeah I am more familiar with Java >.<

Answer (score 0):

The type of `this` is a *pointer* to object of Handler class, but your `setHandler` is expecting `Handler` object. So there is a type mismatch. Change the signature of setHandler to accept a `Handler*` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show `Handler::HandleTCPClient(int, std::string, std::string)`, but presumably within it is something like

```
setHandler (&somehandler);
```

instead of

```
setHandler (somehandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add const:

```
void setHandler(const Handler & h);
```

and

```
void Product::setHandler(const Handler  & h)
{
    handler = h;
}
```

and call:

```
tempProduct.setHandler(this->handler());
```

I dont understand wh you use this operator ???

Answer (score 0):

call

tempProduct.setHandler(*this);